# How to execute more than one query in Firedac Query with Oracle?

Tags: delphi, firedac

Similar to the following expression in FDQuery is executed with more than one result in SQL server:

```
SELECT cod FROM MERCHANDISE
SELECT cod FROM USER
```

How to execute more than one expression when the database is Oracle?

I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
SELECT cod FROM MERCHANDISE;
SELECT cod FROM USER;

[FireDAC][Phys][Ora] ORA-00911: caractere inválido.


other:
begin
   SELECT cod FROM MERCHANDISE;
   SELECT cod FROM USER;
end;
---------------------------
[FireDAC][Phys][Ora] ORA-06550: linha 2, coluna 3:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
ORA-06550: linha 3, coluna 3:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement.
---------------------------
```

Comment: @TLama, oh ok, I'll remove my comment.  Great to see you dropping in here these past few days, btw.

Comment: Returning multiple resultsets should work for anonymous `BEGIN..END` blocks (see notes by [this chapter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Command_Batches_(FireDAC)#DMBS_and_Batches)). Could you elaborate what is the problem (and include your environment description), please?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
With the "begin end" block I described that I had already tried but may be mistaken in using the syntax.

I put in FDQuery sql.text:

begin
   select cod from merchandise;
   select cod from users;
end;

When executing the invalid character error "probably because of the"; "but even without the"; "sql error not properly terminated!

Comment: Have you explored using TFDQuery's NextRecordSet with two simple SELECTs?

Comment: Yes, but only with the SqlServer database, Query opens and navigates between sets in SqlServer. I need to know the syntax to implement Query query with Oracle database.

Comment: Still trying to ...